# ImageTK application won't run

Tags: python, tkinter

I feel this is going to be a very obvious one, but I've been using a commandline version of the pyfaces project for a long time and I am trying to run the GUI version, found here ([Google Code](http://code.google.com/p/pyfaces/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2Fsrc%2Fpyfaces)). I can see it requires ImageTK, and have checked the *imaging, imaging-dbg, imaging-tk, imaging-tk-dbg* are installed but when the code is run, I get no output - not even a windows initialising.

What am I missing?

Comment: how are you trying to run in? the `__main__` is in [pyfacescontroller.py](http://code.google.com/p/pyfaces/source/browse/trunk/src/pyfaces/pyfacescontroller.py), have you tried running that?

Comment: Not only was I calling `pyfacesgui.py` directly, rather than `pyfacescontroller.py` I had an error because I didn't have Tix installed, which I manage to get via the package manager. All working fine, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I suspected I was being stupid. I was not calling the file containing `__main__` so the program would not initialise. Once it was running, a couple of errors were thrown related to packages not being present. For reference here are the packages required (Ubuntu 12.04):

```
python-imaging
python-imaging-dbg
python-imaging-tk
python-imaging-tk-dbg
python-tix
python-tix-dev
```

I'm not entirely sure if all the `dbg` and `dev` packages are needed, please edit if you know.